# Using elementary row operations to find determinant 4x4

Tags: matrices

I need to find the determinant of this matrix $A$ $$\begin{pmatrix}
-1 &  2&  -3& 4\\ 
5 &  0&  2& -2\\ 
 2&  1&  1& 2\\ 
 0&  0&  3& -2
\end{pmatrix}$$ I've found it using the cofactor method and got:
$$\det(A) = 60$$

however i find it difficult to use elementary row operations to find that - can somebody help?

Comment: Could you include the matrix in the question itself pls. (corporate big brother blocking dropbox)

Comment: @rbm - Ive done it

Comment: Thanks - so have you tried to diagonalize the matrix?

Comment: @rbm - yes, I've been trying but haven't been able to get all zeros at the bottom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{pmatrix}
-1 &  2&  -3& 4\\ 
5 &  0&  2& -2\\ 
 2&  1&  1& 2\\ 
 0&  0&  3& -2
\end{pmatrix}\stackrel{R_2+5R_1\;,\;\;R_3+2R_1}\longrightarrow\begin{pmatrix}
-1 &  2&  -3& 4\\ 
0 &  10&  -13& 18\\ 
 0&  5&  -5& 10\\ 
 0&  0&  3& -2
\end{pmatrix}\stackrel{R_3-\frac12R_2}\longrightarrow$$

$$\begin{pmatrix}
-1 &  2&  -3& 4\\ 
0 &  10&  -13& 18\\ 
 0&  0&  1.5& 1\\ 
 0&  0&  3& -2
\end{pmatrix}\stackrel{R_4-2R_3}\longrightarrow\begin{pmatrix}
-1 &  2&  -3& 4\\ 
0 &  10&  -13& 18\\ 
 0&  0&  1.5& 1\\ 
 0&  0&  0& -4
\end{pmatrix}$$

The matrix is now an upper triangular one and its determinant is just the product of its main diagonal's entries...which is certainly $\;60\;$ .